# Does a 401k contribution help you contribute to a Roth IRA?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, contribution

I have read some pretty poor threads on this site after doing some searches.  I would like the following questions answered with the relevant documentation.  Suppose I made $125,000 in the United States in 2014 and contributed $17,500 to an employer's 401k plan.  Assuming no other variables would I be able to contribute the phased out amount (less than $5,500) to a Roth IRA, or the full amount ($5500) based on the $125,000 - $17,500 = $107,500 amount?  I know it is all related to Modified Adjusted Gross Income.  Thanks in advanced and sorry for beating a dead horse.

Comment: By the way, the Roth IRA contribution income limit isn't really an obstacle these days. Assuming you have no money in Traditional IRAs, you can do a backdoor Roth IRA contribution (i.e. contribute to a Traditional IRA, then immediately convert it to a Roth IRA), which has no income limit regardless of filing status, and the result is the same as a regular Roth IRA contribution.

Answer (score 2):

Depends- **If you are filing as single:**

If you contributed to a **traditional** 401k - you can contribute the full $5,500 to a Roth IRA

If you contributed to a **Roth** 401k - you would have a phased amount to contribute to your Roth IRA

Some employers offer both traditional and roth 401k so your answer depends on which one you elected to contribute to.

**Reason:**
It's like you said - it's about the Modified Adjusted Gross Income (MAGI)

If you contributed to a traditional 401k - your MAGI is $107.5k (Under the $114k single filer limit)

If you contributed to a roth 401k then your MAGI is still $125k

**Married filing jointly -** 
You can contribute the full amount to a roth IRA as the limit is $181k

**Married filing separately**
You can't contribute at all to a roth IRA

If you want to learn more about [roth vs traditional](http://abrahamfu.com/2014/02/16/230-traditional-vs-roth-part-1/)

Or if you already [contributed too much to a roth IRA:](http://abrahamfu.com/2014/06/16/contributed-too-much-to-a-roth-ira/)